# countdown timers started before reaching the activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i have an issue in count down timer, my app consist of recyclerview with items , am trying to make app quiz , so when i click an item in recyclerview it start the first activity which is first question with countdown timer , when i click button to move from current activity to another activity it works. but when i click back button to recyclerview the others 4 questions will lunch one after one with thier countdown timers.

**first_five_Questions_questions_1**

```
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton radioButton;
private Button btnDisplay;
private TextView mTextField;
private CountDownTimer myCount;
public long val;




@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_five_questions_q1);
    addListenerOnButton();

}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Rd_Group_first_five_Questions_q1);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_first_Five_Questions_q1);
    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId =radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            myCount.cancel();
            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            if(selectedId==R.id.Rd_btn_three__first_five_questions_q1)
            {
                val++;
                Intent intent = new Intent( first_five_Questions_questions_1.this, first_five_Questions_questions_2.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", val);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else
            {

                //When user Choose Wrong choice
                Intent intent = new Intent( first_five_Questions_questions_1.this, first_five_Questions_questions_2.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", val);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        }

    });

    myCount=new CountDownTimer(16000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimerClock_first_Five_Questions_Q1);
            mTextField.setText("Time left:"+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
           if(millisUntilFinished / 1000 == 5)
           {
               mTextField.setTextColor(Color.RED);
           }
        }


        public void onFinish() {
                                                                                       // When time finish go for mainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent( first_five_Questions_questions_1.this, first_five_Questions_questions_2.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", val);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            cancel();
            finish();
        }

    }.start();
}}
```

**CustomRecyclerAdapterTests**

```
private Context context;
private List<TestsUtils> TestsUTils;


public CustomRecyclerAdapterTests(Context context, List testutils) {

    this.context = context;
    this.TestsUTils = testutils;
}


@Override
public CustomRecyclerAdapterTests.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_list_item_tests, parent, false);
    CustomRecyclerAdapterTests.ViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomRecyclerAdapterTests.ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomRecyclerAdapterTests.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.itemView.setTag(TestsUTils.get(position));
    TestsUtils pu = TestsUTils.get(position);
    holder.Subject_Title.setText(pu.GetTestName());
    holder.Subject_Description.setText(pu.GetTestSubject());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return TestsUTils.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView Subject_Title;
    public TextView Subject_Description;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Subject_Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Title_Single_List_Item_Tests);
        Subject_Description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Subject_Single_List_Item_Tests);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                switch (getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        TestsUtils obj1 = (TestsUtils) view.getTag();
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Test-One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intentone = new Intent(context, com.example.computer.policeproject.Questions_package.First_Five_Questions.first_five_Questions_questions_1.class);
                        context.startActivity(intentone);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        TestsUtils obj2 = (TestsUtils) view.getTag();
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Test-One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intenttwo = new Intent(context, com.example.computer.policeproject.Questions_package.Second_Five_Questions.second_five_questions_questions_1.class);
                        context.startActivity(intenttwo);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

```
if(selectedId==R.id.Rd_btn_three__first_five_questions_q1)
            {
                val++;
                Intent intent = new Intent( first_five_Questions_questions_1.this, first_five_Questions_questions_2.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", val);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else
            {

                //When user Choose Wrong choice
                Intent intent = new Intent( first_five_Questions_questions_1.this, first_five_Questions_questions_2.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", val);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
```

Comment: you need to launch the question activity from RecyclerView adapter based on current position. Can you post your code where you are launching 1st question actvity?

Comment: sure am editing now

Comment: even if i click button  to lunch one and two , when i click button back to back to recyclervew , the other 3 question activitis will lunch with thier countdown timer. and so on ,

Comment: sorry. it is bit tough to understand your problem. do you mind sharing a few screenshots?

Comment: i can send you the project brother

Comment: see when i lunch 1 question , when go back to recyclerview the other 4 questions lunches one after one with thier count down timer.

Comment: yeah, to avoid that. you need to launch the activity from adapter using current positon.

Comment: your code requires lot of re-work. I can only give you hints.

Comment: did u understood my problem?

Comment: its already lunched from adapter

Comment: I understood your problem. I think I also have a solution

Comment: you need to change your Adapter. I am posting the answer now. Also please read how ViewHolder pattern works.

Comment: but the problem is not from the adapter , its from count down timer

Comment: ohhh.. okay I understood now

Comment: you need to handle back clicks. there are couple of ways to do it. Either use onActivityResult or you can also write an interface or you can simply handle it onResume

Comment: so before i reach any question activity when i want to go back to recyclerview , once recyclerview activity lunc , the others questions activity run one after one with thier count down timer.

Comment: yeah. it is because, when you hit back, it starts the counter again when previous activity comes into focus.

Comment: but as u see am using  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); so it means if u r on second question and hit back , should go for recycler, once recycler lunch , the third question lunch , after third question lunch , the forth will lunch , after forth is lunch , the fifth is lunch according to countdown timer.

Comment: so the countdown timer for third , forth , fifth questions one by one when am in recyclerview.

Comment: I posted an answer. please check

Answer (score 0):

add this method in your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  myCount.cancel();
}
```

here is the modified question activity class. see where I pasted onBackPressed() method, copy that in all your question activities.

```
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton radioButton;
private Button btnDisplay;
private TextView mTextField;
private CountDownTimer myCount;
public long val;




@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_five_questions_q1);
    addListenerOnButton();

}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Rd_Group_first_five_Questions_q1);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_first_Five_Questions_q1);
    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId =radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            myCount.cancel();
            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            if(selectedId==R.id.Rd_btn_three__first_five_questions_q1)
            {
                val++;
                Intent intent = new Intent( first_five_Questions_questions_1.this, first_five_Questions_questions_2.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", val);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else
            {

                //When user Choose Wrong choice
                Intent intent = new Intent( first_five_Questions_questions_1.this, first_five_Questions_questions_2.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", val);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        }

    });

    myCount=new CountDownTimer(16000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimerClock_first_Five_Questions_Q1);
            mTextField.setText("Time left:"+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
           if(millisUntilFinished / 1000 == 5)
           {
               mTextField.setTextColor(Color.RED);
           }
        }


        public void onFinish() {
                                                                                       // When time finish go for mainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent( first_five_Questions_questions_1.this, first_five_Questions_questions_2.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", val);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            cancel();
            finish();
        }

    }.start();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  myCount.cancel();
}

}
```

Comment: in your activites.

Comment: no but this is inbuilt method of an acitvity. this method will be called when back button is pressed. this will cancel the timer. You called cancel timer on your own button click

Comment: but my button clicks goes directly to recyclerview , not previos activity

Comment: i will send u the project can u help me with that?

Comment: yeah, sure. I will try

Comment: give me youe email

Comment: i have send the project brother

Comment: yep, I got your project. ill try to look into it

Comment: bro did u checked the project.